# Datepicker shows today's date when using format ''$filter('date')($scope.dt.datetime, 'd MMM, yyyy');' what to do? using angular js datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I want date-picker to show the selected date in the format `15 Jun, 2019`, but instead of the selected date it highlights today's date. But it shows the actual selected date when using the format `2019-06-15` instead.

I am using `angularjs` `date-picker` from [this link](https://mugifly.github.io/jquery-simple-datetimepicker/jquery.simple-dtpicker.html#section_more_methods)

```
<input ng-show="toggleMe" type="text" readonly placeholder="Deadline"
       class="date-picker" ng-datetime-picker="datePickerOptions"
       ng-model="deadlineTask" ng-change="changeCurrentTime()" />
```

// in ng-model wanna show deadlineTask format here what to do that i show format in 'deadlinetask type format an it highlight selected date not the today's date'

```
angular.module('demo', ['ngDatetimePicker'])
.controller('datePickerCtrl',function($scope,$filter) {
    $scope.dt = {};
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
    var date = currentTime.getDate();

    console.log(currentTime);
    $scope.dt.datetime = '2019-06-15';     //showing correct date in this format

    $scope.deadlineTask = $filter('date')($scope.dt.datetime, 'd MMM, yyyy');
```

//showing today's date in this format this format i want but not highlighting the selected date instead of it showing today's date

Comment: The `ng-datetime-picker` directive is not a core AngularJS directive. Did you write it? Or is it a third party library?

Answer (score 0):

You want the datepicker to always be using a date format that you define?

Based on the documentation the datepicker you have chosen does not seem to be able to show the format '15 Jun, 2019'. Maybe have a look at another AngularJs datetime picker if that is the case such as this [one](https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker)

To test it I see from your html that you should have an object called datePickerOptions on $scope?

If that is the case define a property called dateFormat within the datePickerOptions object and give it a string value e.g. 'MM, YYYY'

[Here](https://github.com/mugifly/jquery-simple-datetimepicker/blob/master/jquery.simple-dtpicker.html) you can see this is how they define the date format of an input field:

Here are the formatting options listed:

- YYYY: Year, 4 digit
- YY: Year, 2 digit
- MM: Month, 01-12
- M: Month, 1-12
- DD: Day, 01-31
- D: Day, 1-31
- HH: Hour using 12-hour clock 01-12
- H: Hour using 12-hour clock 1-12
- hh: Hour using 24-hour clock 00-23
- h: Hour using 24-hour clock 0-23
- mm: Minute, 00-59>
- m: Minute, 0-59
- tt: am/pm
- TT: AM/PM

Comment: to be vary simple date picker not highlighting the selected date rather then it is showing last modifying date Eg-: if I select 6/10/2019 after it if i select another date(e.g. 20/10/2019) which is  saved in database it will keep on highlighting 6/10/2019

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input ng-show="toggleMe" type="text" readonly placeholder="Deadline" class="date-picker" ng-datetime-picker="datePickerOptions" ng-model="dt.datetime" ng-change="changeCurrentTime()" />








 <script>
    angular.module('demo', ['ngDatetimePicker']).
    controller('datePickerCtrl', function($scope,$filter) {
    $scope.dt = {};
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
    var date = currentTime.getDate();
    currentTime = year + "-" + month + "-" +"29"+ " 9:00";
    $scope.dt.datetime = '2019-06-15';
    $scope.deadlineTask = $filter('date')($scope.dt.datetime, 'd MMM, yyyy');
    $scope.toggleMe = false;

    $scope.datePickerOptions = {
    "closeOnSelected": true,
    "firstDayOfWeek": 1,
    "dateOnly": true
    };

    $scope.datetimePickerOptions = {
    "closeOnSelected": true,
    "firstDayOfWeek": 1
    };

    });
```

Comment: You should edit your question and put this there, not as an answer.